# How do I reverse a dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first attempt of reversing a dynamic array:

```
bool reverse()
{
    T *newArray = NULL;
            
    // Validate operation.
    if (!isValid() || isReadOnly())
        return false;

    // Allocate new array
    newArray = new (std::nothrow)T[m_size];
    if (newArray == NULL)
        return false;

    // Reverse the array's contents.
    for (int i = m_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        newArray[i] = m_array[i];

    // Delete old array.
    delete[] m_array; 
    m_array = NULL;

    // Assign new array 
    m_array = newArray; 
        
    return true;
}
```

As you can imagine, this is very costly for large arrays:

- Allocation and dealocation takes time.
- A linear algorithm with 'for' takes time, too.

I'm aware of std::reverse, but unfortunately it doesn't work on dynamic arrays.

Should I use std::vector? Yes. But this is for learning. I'm reading from a data structures game programming book and extending my learning.

So I'm interested in reducing this member function of Array to the algorithm itself:

```
    // Reverse the array's contents.
    for (int i = m_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        newArray[i] = m_array[i];
```

I feel like there's an easy way to go about this that is much less costly. I looked on Google but I'm just finding solutions for static arrays.

Extra:

I'm trying std::reverse again, but no luck so far.

```
std::reverse(std::begin(m_array), std::end(m_array));
```

Error on compile:

> error C2672: 'begin': no matching overloaded function found

Also, std::end wouldn't know the end of a dynamic array, as no size is specified, so maybe I'm just using the wrong functions to achieve this goal. It'd be nice to use std::reverse somehow.

Comment: "I'm aware of std::reverse, but unfortunately it doesn't work on dynamic arrays."  `std::reverse` works on just about _anything_.

Comment: Any `reverse` algorithm is going to be lienar time by definition.

Comment: I tried it for dynamic arrays, but had no luck. Maybe there's a different argument list that better fits for dynamic arrays.

Comment: Your current implementation has the strong-exception-guarantee, and works on arbitrary types. Are those features we need to preserve?  If so, allocation and deallocation are also required, and cannot be optimized out

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thanks. I didn't think of that one.

Comment: @PhilC: you can most certainly use `std::reverse()` with dynamic arrays. What you can't use with dynamic arrays is `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, so you will have to use pointers instead.  Better to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly, though. You can use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` with a vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::reverse(m_array+0, m_array+m_size);
```

`std::reverse` takes iterators as parameters, and pointers are one form of iterator.

Comment: Please note that +0 is not necessary, as m_array points to the first cell.

Comment: @Phil The symmetry is nice though.

Comment: @PhilC: `m_array` is an array that decays to a pointer that happens to point to the first cell. `m_array+m_size` is a pointer. `std::reverse` might have trouble figuring out the right parameter types when given an array and a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine as you can use pointers with every std function which can use iterators:

```
int size = 10;
int *i = new int[size];
iota(i, i + size, 0);
copy(i, i + size, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
reverse(i, i + size);
copy(i, i + size, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
> ```

You can check this article [Raw pointers are also Iterators!](http://cppisland.com/?p=134).

Answer (score 1):

You could manually swap the starting indices with the ending indices to effectively reverse the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int* array = new int[6]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    constexpr std::size_t size = 6;

    //swap ending and starting iterators
    for (std::size_t index = 0, end = size / 2; index != end; ++index) {
        std::swap(array[index], array[size - index - 1]);
    }

    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != size; ++index) {
        std::cout << array[index] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::reverse(array, array + size);

    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != size; ++index) {
        std::cout << array[index] << ' ';
    }

    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

`std::reverse` Will also work since it accepts a starting and ending iterator to which pointers can act as iterators.

Comment: This drops a few potentially important properties, as explored in comments under the question.